# get list of decision for a specific meetingtitle using linq asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, linq

I have a database table. What I want is to get data using `group by` clause as I have used in below code.
Note that Decision is another table. now I want that all the decisions related to a specific Meeting Title should be shown in list.like
meetingtitle1=decision1,decison2,decison3 
meetingtitle2=decision1,decison2
but below code returns only one decisiontitle.

```
public List<NewMeetings> GetAllMeetings()
       {

           var xyz = (from m in DB.MeetingAgenda
                      //join mp in Meeting on m.MeetingId equals mp.MeetingId
                      //where m.MeetingId == 2
                      group m by new { m.Meeting.MeetingTitle } into grp
                      select new NewMeetings
                      {
                          //  meetingid = grp.Key.MeetingId,
                          meetingtitle = grp.Key.MeetingTitle,
                          decision = grp.Select(x => x.Decision.DecisionTitle).FirstOrDefault(),

                          total = grp.Count()
                      }).ToList();

           List<NewMeetings> list = xyz.ToList();
           return list;



       }

       public class NewMeetings
       {
           public int meetingid;
           public string meetingtitle;
           public string decision;
           public int total;
       }
```

Can somebody please tell me how to return a list of decisions to a specific Meetingtitle?

Comment: Try to remove the `FirstOrDefault( )` when you select the decisions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a `FirstOrDefault` on the list of decisions which obviously means you are only getting a single value. Instead you can join them all together into one longer string (separated by commas as you indicated in the question) by changing this line:

```
decision = grp.Select(x => x.Decision.DecisionTitle).FirstOrDefault(),
```

To this:

```
decision = string.Join(",", grp.Select(x => x.Decision.DecisionTitle)),
```

However, as the `string.Join` is not recognised by Linq to Entities, you need to do the `string.Join` after the data has been retrieved (i.e. after the `ToList`):

```
   var xyz = (from m in DB.MeetingAgenda
              group m by new { m.Meeting.MeetingTitle } into grp
              select new
              {
                  meetingtitle = grp.Key.MeetingTitle,
                  decisions = grp.Select(x => x.Decision.DecisionTitle),
                  total = grp.Count()
              })
              .ToList()
              .Select(m => new NewMeetings
              {
                  meetingtitle = m.meetingtitle,
                  decision = string.Join(",", m.decisions),
                  total = m.total
              });
```

Comment: i have tested your provided solution but got this error.   LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method,

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that. I've made a change.